# from models import Category ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models' using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

settings.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class CategoryConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'api.category'
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

admin.py code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Category
admin.site.register(Category)
```

apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class CategoryConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'api.category'
```

Error in the terminal:

> *File "/home/kickme/Desktop/lcodev/ecom/api/category/admin.py", line 2,*
> *in* 
> *from models import Category ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'*

Answer (score 1):

In the admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from models import Category #this line is responsible for the break

admin.site.register(Category)
```

If your models.py ss in the same directory then use

```
from .models import Category
```

This means to import the model Category from the models.py file in the same directory

Comment: My models.py, admin.py and apps.py are in same folder and after executing this code  from .models import Category i m getting this error     ""from .models import Category
ImportError: cannot import name 'Category' from partially initialized module 'api.category.models'""

Comment: I am using linux operating system